# User authentication with Axios using React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to make a transition to redux in developing my web app.

I realized that after I specify the types in my `actions`, I can dispatch it to my `reducers` and the `reducers` will perform changes based on the types of the `actions`.

I have two `actions` that looks like this:

```
export const doLogin = (username, password) => {
    return {
        type: types.AUTH_LOGIN,
        username,
        password
    };
};

export const doLogout = () => ({
  type: types.AUTH_LOGOUT,
});
```

I can dispatch these two actions to my `reducer` that looks like:

```
const initialState = {
  username: "",
  isLoggedIn: false
};

const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.AUTH_LOGIN:
      return {
        ...state, // Preserve states that are unchanged
        username: action.username, // Values to be changed
        isLoggedIn: true
      };
    case types.AUTH_LOGOUT:
      return initialState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

My `reducer` currently just creates a new state `username: username, isLoggedin: true` and returns it. It has NOTHING to do with actual user authentication.

Before switching to `Redux`, I did my user authentication by calling an API Post using `Axios`.

The code looked like:

```
 axios.post('http://localhost:5000/signin', 
 {
     username:this.state.username, 
     password:this.state.password
 })
     .then(function (response) {

     console.log(response);
     if(response.data.status === "Successful"){
         console.log("Login successfull");
         this.setState({loggedOn:true})
     }

     else{
         console.log("There is no user with the given username and password");
         //alert("Username does not exist");
     }
     }
 )
 .catch(function (error) {

 console.log(error);
 });
```

I am not sure how and where this has to be incorporated to `Redux`. Do I have to put it into my `reducers`, or `actions`?

Please help.

**EDIT**

I am already using `redux-thunk`

**store.js**

```
import rootReducer from "../reducers";
import ReduxThunk from "redux-thunk";

const middlewares = [ReduxThunk];
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
```

**index.js**

```
import store from "./store";
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';


console.log('init state', store.getState());
store.subscribe(()=>console.log(store.getState()));
store.dispatch(actions.doLogin('sample', '1234'));
```

`actions.doLogin` gives me the error `Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the dispatch function as below

```
export const doLogin = (username, password) => {
    return dispatch => {
        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/signin', {
            username: username,
            password: password
        })
        .then((response)=>{
            dispatch({
                type: AUTH_LOGIN,
                username: response.username
            })
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            console.log("There is no user with the given username and password");
            //alert("Username does not exist");
        })
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems like it's working. Could you please explain how it actually works step-by-step? What does the syntax `dispatch => { ...` do? And how does the second `dispatch` in the code work?

Comment: That's a function used from redux-thunk that waits for the request to response, and then return what you return from the second dispatch

Comment: In my understanding, doing `dispatch(functionName)` will send the action to the reducer. In reducer, it will return new states based on the action type. Is it correct? In your answer, I am confused because I am not sure what happens if we pass in an object to a dispatch, not a function.

Answer (score 1):

The reducers just receive the state change. So, your action should contain the authentication. Then, when it's complete and the user was authenticated, it returns to the reducer. Like this:

```
export const doLogin = (username, password) => {
     var auth = false
     axios.post('http://localhost:5000/signin', 
     {
         username:this.state.username, 
         password:this.state.password
     }).then(response => {
         console.log(response);
         if(response.data.status === "Successful"){
             console.log("Login successfull");
             auth = true;
         }
         else{
             console.log("There is no user with the given username and password");
             //alert("Username does not exist");
         }
      }).catch(function (error) {
           console.log(error);
      });
      if(auth) return {
             type: types.AUTH_LOGIN,
             username,
             password
      }
};

export const doLogout = () => ({
  type: types.AUTH_LOGOUT,
});
```

> Advise: That's not a good pratice. It's better to maintain the authentication 
>     in a script or inside the component. Then, when it's sucessful, it emmits the
>     action to the Redux. I'd tried this a couple times, and noticed that it's not
>     the best way.

Comment: Looks great. But when I try to test it by doing `store.dispatch(actions.doLogin('sample', '1234'));`, it gives me an error saying `Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.` Any idea?

Comment: That's the problem. The `axios.post()` is async, and your action cannot be async. Take a look at [Redux-Thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk), it makes it possible.

Comment: The thing is, I am already using Redux-Thunk. Please take a look at my edit.

Comment: Read this article https://medium.com/@stowball/a-dummys-guide-to-redux-and-thunk-in-react-d8904a7005d3

Comment: Thanks that is a useful link and I will look into it. However, are you able to point out  the reason why the error comes up even I use `redux-thunk`?